# How to generate normally distributed random number

Tags: matlab, random, gaussian, normal-distribution

can someone explain or point me to a page that explain how to create normally distributed random number in matlab using just error function, the inverse of the error function, and rand()(uniform random number generator between 0 and 1)? the random number doesn't have to be bounded to a certain interval. I'm having problem understand the concept of the error function and the inverse of it, and how it relates to creating random number that is normally distribute

Comment: Just use the `randn` function: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/randn.html. This sounds suspiciously like a homer=work problem.

Comment: "*the random number doesn't have to be bounded to a certain interval*"   Note the [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is unbounded (unless you impose [truncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution)).

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the method called [**inverse transform sampling**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), which consists in the following. Assume you want to generate a random variable with a given distribution function *F*. If you can compute the inverse function *F*<sup>-1</sup>, then you can obtain the desired random variable by applying *F*<sup>-1</sup> to random samples with uniform distribution on the interval [0,1].

The error function ([`erf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/erf.html) in Matlab) *almost* gives the distribution function of a normal random variable. Its inverse function is called [`erfinv`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/erfinv.html) in Matlab. Uniformly distributed random numbers are generated with [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/rand.html).

With these ingredients you should be able to do the task. Please give it a try, and *then* see the code hovering the mouse over the rectangle:

> `N = 1e6;                    % number of samples` 
>  `x = erfinv(2*rand(1,N)-1);  % note factor 2, because of definition of erf` 
>  `hist(x,31)                  % plot histogram to check it is (approximately) normal`

Comment: Neat trick with the mouse-hover. Is there an easy way to do it, or did you have to type the `>!` etc. by hand?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks! By hand. The most tedious part is the backticks and `<br>`'s to split the code in lines

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/random-numbers-with-specific-mean-and-variance.html) from Mathworks seems to give the answer.

Here's the example from the link:

```
% First, initialize the random number generator to make the results in this
% example repeatable.
rng(0,'twister');

% Create a vector of 1000 random values drawn from a normal distribution
% with a mean of 500 and a standard deviation of 5.
a = 5;
b = 500;
y = a.*randn(1000,1) + b;

% Calculate the sample mean, standard deviation, and variance.
stats = [mean(y) std(y) var(y)]

% stats =
% 
%   499.8368    4.9948   24.9483
%
% The mean and variance are not 500 and 25 exactly because they are
% calculated from a sampling of the distribution.
```